# Child Passport Query

Tags: passports

I would appreciate some advice. We live in the UK but have a sudden requirement to visit Japan (family reasons).  My 4 month old son has a Japanese passport but his UK one will more than likely not be ready in time for the trip.

Would it be allowed for him to fly out of the UK on his Japanese passport, and also return on it, without a UK one?  Would it mean when we fly back to the UK that he is only allowed in as a tourist?
Are there any other complications i need to consider?

Searched for the guidance but is hard to find anything.
Many Thanks
Graham

Comment: Son has British citizenship?

Comment: This is a duplicate.  Both Japan and the US (in the canonical question) are non-visa national countries.  Appendix V of the rules apply.  Nice checking @CMaster